# Validating filename in Bash

Tags: bash

I want to validate a file name in bash to make sure that I don't have this '[]' character in it

I have this  :

```
if ! [[ $filename=~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]; then
    echo 'Wrong filename input' >&2 
    exit 1
fi
```

but I want explicitly avoid [] and allow other special characters.

any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to disallow `[` and `]`?

Comment: to make sure duplicates files in windows(which usually have filename[1] ...etc) are not uploaded.

Answer (score 5):

Use spaces around `=~` operator:

```
[[ ! "$filename" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]] && echo "bad filename" || echo "its good"
```

OR your own script:

```
if [[ ! "$filename" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]; then
    echo 'Wrong filename input' >&2 
    exit 1
fi
```

**Update:**

If you want to explicitly avoid only `[` and `]` then following check is better:

```
if [[ "$filename" == *[]\[]* ]]; then
    echo 'Wrong filename input' >&2 
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Or maybe even, `[[ "$filename" =~ \[ ]] || [[ "$filename" =~ \] ]] && echo "Bad filename"`

Comment: Yes that can also be done if intent is to just avoid matching `[` and `]`

Comment: I just added that to comply with the *specs* :) -- `but I want explicitly avoid []`

Comment: @devnull: Alright thanks, I edited my answer to just avoid matching `[` and `]`

Comment: Which happens to be aproximatelly what I had already posted :)

Comment: @fedorqui: `"$filename" == *[]*` doesn't work if filename is: `ab[`

Comment: @anubhava but the request is `to make sure that I don't have this '[]' character in it`

Comment: @fedorqui: Yes true your check will fail only when filename has `[]`

Comment: @fedorqui: You misunderstood, I meant your check will print `bad` when filenames contains `[]`

Comment: I see, my bad. I just didn't like you updating from a previous different approach to something so close to mine without considering to suggest an improvement to mine. Anyway, deleting mine to avoid redundancy.

Comment: @fedorqui: Sorry didn't mean to take anything away. I kept original answer to show where exactly OP was making mistake. It is just I got a comment and without looking below posted an update.

Comment: No problem, I guess I over exaggerated so apologize me :)

Comment: @fedorqui: No problem at all, and there is no need to apologize. I have learnt a lot from your answers on SO.